# need clicked twice on html anchor to go to id or name

Tags: html, vue.js, firefox, anchor

I have this little problem happen on firefox (works fine on chrome), i have list of buttons that have anchor with different in page destination, im using id, but (on firefox) the anchor only work on second click, the first click only change the URL.

```
<a href="#section1">button 1</a>
<a href="#section2">button 2</a>
```

destination

```
<section id="section1">
some content
</section>
<section id="section2">
some content
</section>
```

ive also already try name="" but its still need double clikc to work, is there method to resolve this or is it a bug on firefox?

Comment: You can try disable all the addons or run the firefox as safe mode and try the application again.

Comment: @HelloPutra thanks for the reply, tried that but its still not working mate

Comment: For posterity, if anybody comes here looking for Remix.js solution for the same, replace `<a href="...">` with `<Link to="...">` and anchors will work from single-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('section1').scrollIntoView(true);">
    Button 1
</a>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('section2').scrollIntoView(true);">
    Button 2
</a>
```

Destination :

```html
<section id="section1">
    some content
</section>
<section id="section2">
    some content
</section>
```

Comment: its work like a charm, actually i tried not to use javascript, i thought this this kind of action dont need js since it works fine on other browser, im using vue so im move it to methods, thanks for the answer very helpfull, but i still wonder is this bug on firefox or no haha

Comment: Yep, maybe it's bug or maybe it's feature xD

Answer (score 1):

I can verify the issue exists in Firefox and Safari. This can be solved without JS by configuring your router's scrollBehavior as mentioned in the docs ([Router v3](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) | [Router v4](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)):

A solution would look like this for Router V3:

```js
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash };
    } 
  }
```

Or for Router V4:

```js
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { el: to.hash };
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are a hero, my friend! Thanks